# metatrader error initialize() failed, error code = (-10005, 'IPC timeout')

Tags: python, metatrader5

I got this error
**initialize() failed, error code = (-10005, 'IPC timeout')**
when execute this code:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
# display data on the MetaTrader 5 package
print("MetaTrader5 package author: ",mt5.__author__)
print("MetaTrader5 package version: ",mt5.__version__)
 
# establish connection to the MetaTrader 5 terminal
if not mt5.initialize(login=999999, server="xyz-Demo",password="abcdef"):
    print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
    mt5.shutdown()
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved it.
I divided the process into two:

1. I did the initialization and then,
2. I logged in.

Importantly, I'm using a Windows PC and everything started working when I changed the path from

```
"C:\Program Files\MetaTrader 5\terminal64.exe"
```

to

```
"C:/Program Files/MetaTrader 5/terminal64.exe"
```

The code:

```
def account_login(login = name,password=key, server= serv,):
    if mt5.login(login,password,server):
        print("logged in succesffully")
    else: 
        print("login failed, error code: {}".format(mt5.last_error()))

def initialize(login = name, server=serv, password=key, path=path):
    
    if not mt5.initialize(path):
        print("initialize() failed, error code {}", mt5.last_error())
    else:
        account_login(login, password, server)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. Clean code, detailed explanation and just works.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some solutions to your problem:

1. Try initializing a connection to the MT5 terminal using `mt5.initialize()` then login into the trading account using `mt5.login(account, server, password)`.
2. Try closing all previous connections to the mt5 terminal using `mt5.shutdown()` on all previous scripts

Answer (score -6):

Maybe, We must launch the app.
In actually, I solved same issue by launch the app.